# Is there any app, that is similar to EXPO, which can be used to run the javascript application on ios device, without publishing to app store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to develop a cross-platform mobile application.
I have spent some time on EXPO. Even though EXPO has many merits (easy OTA updates, push notifications etc), It has many downfalls which made me not to continue working with EXPO, instead I will work on a pure react-native project.

One thing I like about EXPO is you don't need to have your own mac to test your application, instead you can start server by `expo-cli start` and use expo client app on your iphone connected to same LAN.

If I switch to pure react-native development, I want to know if there are any applications similar to expo client app which can run my javascript application on ios device?

Comment: expo is the only major platform you can use to test react native on iPhones without actually having a mac unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Harrison

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are alternatives

You can use https://appcenter.ms/

It's visual studio app center they also support Over the air updates OTA

That is called CodePush by Microsoft

you must case study this as well